# Add java.awt.Image to itext directly

Tags: java, image, itext

I was wondering if you could add a java.awt.Image to itext directly; all the responses to this question I've seen so far suggest to write the image to disk

```
   ImageIO.write(img, "png", "output.png);
```

Then fetch it using the com.itextpdf.text.Image method `Image.getInstance()`

```
   Image iTextImage = Image.getInstance("output.png");
```

This solution works but is not quite elegant. Is there any way to do this better?

Comment: The long answer is below. The short answer is: have you tried the autocompletion suggestions that your IDE gives you? Probably not, because then you didn't have to ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the iText [API documentation for the Image class](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html), then you will see that there are many other ways than a filename to use an image:

- `static Image getInstance(byte[] imgb)`
- `static Image getInstance(byte[] imgb, boolean recoverFromImageError)` gets an instance of an `Image`
- `static Image getInstance(Image image)` gets an instance of an `Image`
- `static Image getInstance(Image image, Color color)` Gets an instance of an `Image` from a `java.awt.Image`.
- `static Image getInstance(Image image, Color color, boolean forceBW)` Gets an instance of an `Image` from a `java.awt.Image`.
- `static Image getInstance(int width, int height, boolean reverseBits, int typeCCITT, int parameters, byte[] data)` Creates an `Image` with CCITT G3 or G4 compression.
- `static Image getInstance(int width, int height, boolean reverseBits, int typeCCITT, int parameters, byte[] data, int[] transparency)` Creates an `Image` with CCITT G3 or G4 compression.
- `static Image getInstance(int width, int height, byte[] data, byte[] globals)` Creates a JBIG2 `Image`.
- `static Image getInstance(int width, int height, int components, int bpc, byte[] data)` Gets an instance of an `Image` in raw mode.
- `static Image getInstance(int width, int height, int components, int bpc, byte[] data, int[] transparency)` Gets an instance of an `Image` in raw mode.
- `static Image getInstance(PdfContentByte cb, Image awtImage, float quality)` Gets an instance of a `Image` from a `java.awt.Image`.
- `static Image getInstance(PdfTemplate template)` gets an instance of an `Image`
- `static Image getInstance(PdfWriter writer, Image awtImage, float quality)` Gets an instance of a `Image` from a `java.awt.Image`.
- `static Image getInstance(PRIndirectReference ref)` Reuses an existing image.
- `static Image getInstance(String filename)` Gets an instance of an `Image`
- `static Image getInstance(String filename, boolean recoverFromImageError)`
- `static Image getInstance(URL url)`
- `static Image getInstance(URL url, boolean recoverFromImageError)` Gets an instance of an `Image`.

You can find an example on how to use a `java.awt.Image` on the official web site. See the [ImageTypes](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-10#401-imagetypes.java) example:

```
// Adding a java.awt.Image
java.awt.Image awtImage =
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(RESOURCE);
img = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(awtImage, null);
document.add(new Paragraph(
    String.format("%s is an image of type %s",
    "java.awt.Image", img.getClass().getName())));
document.add(img);
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno for cleaning up my answer. (I guess) :D

Comment: I often have the same problem: answering from a phone isn't easy if you need to copy links and code snippets.